# React Native - Map elements two on a row

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an array of objects in React Native. What is the simplest way to map them two on a row like in the following picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGWTr.png

I have a function that converts an array into an array of arrays of 2 elements:

```
{/* Example input: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] */}
{/* Example output: [ [0, 1] , [2, 3] , [4, 5] , [6, 7] ] */}
```

then simply map each element into a View that contains two other View elements, but seems way too overkill.

Is there a simpler method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, there is a simpler way. You could set width 50% to each element and to the parent set flexDirection: 'row' and flexWrap: 'wrap'

Comment: what if it's an odd number of elements? the last one will be right in the middle of the screen

Comment: I don't remember exactly how I used to fix that, but play with the alignment. If elements use 50% of the space you don't need them to be aligned to the center.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of map, the Better way is to Use `FlatList` with prop`numColumns={2}`

```js
<FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        numColumns={2}
      />
```

**Full Example:**

Working Demo: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/flatlisttwocolumns)

**Output:**

[image]

**Source Code:**

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={list}
        numColumns={2}
        keyExtractor={(item)=> item}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View style={styles.card}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{item}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  card: {
    height: 100,
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#212121',
    boxShadow: "10px 10px 0px -5px rgba(209,25,209,1)",
    margin: 5,
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 40,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: 'white',
  },
});
```